# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> ERROR: Failed to resolve:
>   com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1
>
> Show in Project
>
> Structure dialog Affected Modules: app I have also use the maven
>
> like:  maven {
>
> url  'https//dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven'
>
> }

But didn't get the solution. Please help.

//App level grade code:

[image]

Comment: share app level build.gradle file code

Answer (score 1):

Change to this
implementation 'com.github.kmenager:material-animated-switch:1.2.2'

Comment: This is works https://github.com/kmenager/material-animated-switch

Answer (score 0):

move maven to allProjects like below

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
    }
  }
}
```

for more check [here](https://github.com/glomadrian/material-animated-switch/issues/27#issuecomment-412380637)

Comment: @MD.AsifHossainRibhu if this post help to resolve your issue. Do upvote and mark as accept like https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Comment: HI @MD.AsifHossainRibhu if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You must add `url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"` to the project level gradle and `com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar` dependency to the app level gradle.

> Project level Gradle

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
    }
  }
}
```

> App level Gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar' // Add the dependency
```